# Comparing values in two PHP arrays, problem adding more values to one of the arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm comparing values in two arrays, one created from a local database (***$dbArray***) while loop, and the other fetched from a API (***$tmdbArray***). This is working. But now I want to add another value (***id***) from the local database (***$dbArray***), and I can't get that to work.

This is working:

```
<?php
// database names
$dbArray = array();
while($rowMatch = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlTitlePerson)){
    $dbArray[] = trim(preg_replace("/\([^)]*\)/", '', $rowMatch['name']));
}

// tmdb names
$tmdbArray = array();
foreach($credits['cast'] as $credit){
    if(!in_array($credit['name'], $dbArray)){
        $tmdbArray[] = $credit['name'];
    }
}

foreach ($tmdbArray as $castArray){
    echo $castArray.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Now I want to add a id from the local database, which is in ***$rowMatch['id']***.
How can I add ***$rowMatch['id']*** to the ***$dbArray[]***?

```
$dbArray[] = $rowMatch['id'];
```

I have tested several solutions, but none works for me, and I don't know why.

Thanks,

Comment: Please describe why you believe it is not working. Is there an error, incorrect values, replacement of values, extra values, no value being pushed to the array, etc? Also please show in the code you posted where you are attempting to use `$dbArray[] = $rowMatch['id'];`.

Comment: If you put that line right  before or after the one that adds `$rowMatch['name']`, it should work (assuming the SQL query selects both the `id` and`name` columns). I'm not sure why you want to have both values in the same array, though. Usually an array should contain uniform data, not a mix of names and IDs.

Comment: BTW, you can use `array_filter()` in place of the second loop.

Comment: You can also use `array_intersect()` to find all the values that are in common between two arrays: `$tmpdbArray = array_intersect(array_column($credits['cast'], 'name'), $dbArray);`